# c++ using struct for private member variables

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct, private-members

here is what I need to do for my homework

---

data members representing the: name, address, city, state and ZIP code for both the
sender and the recipient of the package, in addition to data members that store the weight
(in ounces) and cost per ounce to ship the package.

---

these are the memb vars for my class, and it says I need the name,address, city, state, and zip for both sender and recipient, so I think i should make a struct with those 5 variables, and just made 2 instances of the struct one for sender and one for recipient instead of making 2 names, adresses and etc...

But idk if thats possible or right to do, and how to do it?
Any help?

Thanks)

Here is what I have:

```
class Package {
private:
    string name;
    string adress;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
    double weight;
    double costPerOunce;
public:
    <#member functions#>
};
```

Also here is what I need for this class, and also another question. How would I initialize the struct members for class, and do the set fuctions if my member vars are struct? How would the syntax look like?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why isn't the current layout enough?

Comment: Sure you can: `Person sender, recipient;` assuming you've declared what a Person struct is first.  You can also have a function like `set_sender( Person p );` if you want to set them outside of the constructor.

Comment: @DaveS I just dont know where in the header file I should declare the Person struct?

Comment: Before the class definition.  struct Person .... ;  class Package ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your struct outside of your Package Class. As for initializing the variables within the struct, I believe Dave S offered a good solution in having a separate set function. This way you can call your set function within your constructor for the sender and recipient which will avoid code duplication.